# Recreate new car smell

Tags: toyota, smell, interior, used

I bought a second hand Toyota Sienna 4 months ago. Even though it is a 2009 with  100,000km on it, the interior had that "new car" smell to it, and held it for several weeks.

Four months later, the smell is gone, so I'm assuming that they sprayed something before the sell. Anyone knows what that could be?

Comment: I was told that it was shredded polyester scraps from the manufacturing line.

Comment: If you ever have your windshield replaced (driving under black walnut trees in late summer may help in this regard) you'll find the "new car" smell is back. I've had multiple replacements (only one of which, alas, was black walnut-induced :-) and every time my car smelled like it was back on the showroom floor. So at least some of it appears to be the volatiles in the adhesive used to attach the windshield to the frame. YMMV.

Comment: As an aside, some manufacturers now sell new car smell as an option: http://www.themanufacturer.com/articles/new-bmw-7-series-to-come-with-a-choice-of-eight-new-car-smells/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several products that claim to install a new car smell. Meguiar's G4216 New Car Scent Protectant is one of many that are available. Smell is a very subjective so reviews vary on these products. 
Automotive detailers use products not available on the retail market; one of these is likely what you smelled in your used car.

Here is an article on the subject.  [Car and Driver on new car smell](http://www.caranddriver.com/features/secrets-of-that-new-car-smell)